# Junit Test with envers

Tags: java, hibernate, junit5, entitymanager, hibernate-envers

I 've trying to test a service which uses hibernate envers to perform a rollback. Everything is working fine but the test is driving me mad.

This is the beginning of the service:

```
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
@Service
public class ObjectRollbackServiceImpl implements ObjectRollbackService {

  @Autowired
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Autowired private ObjectRollbackRepository objectRollbackRepository;

  private void restorePreviousVersionOfObject(Long id, Boolean isDelete) {

    AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);

    List<Number> revNumbers = auditReader.getRevisions(ObjectEntity.class, id);
```

And this is the test:

```
class ObjectRollbackServiceTests {

  private static final Long objectId = 1L;
  @InjectMocks
  ObjectRollbackServiceImpl objectRollbackServiceImpl;
  @Mock
  ObjectRollbackRepository objectRollbackRepository;

  @PersistenceUnit
  private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;


  @Mock
  AuditReader auditReader;


  @BeforeEach
  void setUp() throws Exception {
    MockitoAnnotations.openMocks(this);

  }

  @Test
  void testRestorePreviousVersionOfEditedObjectOk() {
    ObjectEntity object = ObjectEntity.builder().build();
    List<Number> listRevisions = Lists.newArrayList();
    listRevisions.add(1);

    when(auditReader.getRevisions(any(), any(Long.class))).thenReturn(listRevisions);
    when(auditReader.find(any(), any(Long.class), any(Number.class))).thenReturn(object);
    when(objectRollbackRepository.findById(any(Long.class))).thenReturn(Optional.of(object));
    when(objectRollbackRepository.saveAndFlush(any(ObjectEntity.class))).thenReturn(object);
    doNothing().when(objectRollbackRepository).updateAuditDates(any(ZonedDateTime.class)
    , any(Integer.class)
    , any(AuditorBO.class)
    , any(Long.class));

    doNothing().when(objectRollbackRepository).deleteRevisionsNotEqualsToCurrentAndPrevious(any(Integer.class), any(Long.class));

    assertDoesNotThrow(() -> objectRollbackServiceImpl.restorePreviousVersionOfEditedObject(1L));


  }



}
```

So the problem is that entityManager is null when trying to execute this line:

AuditReader auditReader = AuditReaderFactory.get(entityManager);

What am I missing?

Comment: Does ObjectRollbackServiceImpl contain constructor or setters to inject the mocks?
 
https://javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/latest/org/mockito/InjectMocks.html

Comment: With this code, it seems difficult to have auditReader as a mock in  ObjectRollbackServiceImpl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try mocking `AuditReaderFactory.get` to give you the mocked AuditReader instance.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21105403/1319284) with its answers for further reference.

So, in your case it could look something like this (code adapted from one of the answers to the other question):

```
  @Test
  public void testStaticMockWithVerification() {
    try (MockedStatic<AuditReaderFactory> dummy = Mockito.mockStatic(AuditReaderFactory.class)) {
      dummy.when(() -> AuditReaderFactory.get(Mockito.any(EntityManager.class)))
        .thenReturn(auditReader);

      factory.getConnection();

    }
  }
```

And instead of using the @Mock annotation, probably create the Mock ObjectRollbackServiceImpl instance in some setup method or static initialization block, so you can set this static mock up beforehand.

Answer (score 2):

You are using `@AllArgsConstructor` so it is creating behind the scenes a constructor with the following signature:

```
ObjectRollbackServiceImpl(EntityManager entityManager,
                          ObjectRollbackRepository objectRollbackRepository)
```

So when you use `@InjectMocks` it expects you to mock the parameters of the constructor:

```
@Mock
EntityManager entityManager;
@Mock
ObjectRollbackRepository objectRollbackRepository;
@InjectMocks
ObjectRollbackServiceImpl objectRollbackServiceImpl;
```

Answer (score 1):

you autowired the entityManager. when you apply @PersistenceUnit on entityManager fields it tries to create the real instance. But we need a mock instance. Apply @Mock and try.

Comment: I have changed to Mock but it shows the next error:

org.opentest4j.AssertionFailedError: Unexpected exception thrown: org.hibernate.envers.exception.AuditException: Hibernate EntityManager not present!

Comment: you could try this: reference: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51963750/not-able-to-mock-persistencecontext-in-spring-boot-test